# The results of the map function in the frontend and backend are output differently

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I got an array by executing the find function in `mongoose`.
After that, I tried to extract only the values ​​of the data using map.
But only `undefined` is returned.

I have created an example below. When I run the map function on the frontend and the backend, the results are different.

I don't know why the results are different. Also, is there a way to get the result of number 2 in the backend code?

example mongodb data

```
{name: 'aaa'},
{name: 'bbb'}
```

backend code

```
router.get("/getValue", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Schema.find({}, "-_id");
    console.log(result); // original data
    let one = result.map((v) => v.name); // 1
    res.send({ success: true, result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send({ success: false });
  }
});
```

frontend code

```
axios.get("/api/getValue").then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        const second = res.data.result.map((v) => v.name); //2
      }
    });
```

result

```
// original data
[{name: 'aaa'}, {name: 'bbb'}]

// 1
[undefined, undefined]

// 2
['aaa', 'bbb']
```

Comment: Please log the result property to the console and share that value

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the schema declaration. While editing the schema data, it was confirmed that the name of the key was entered incorrectly.

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  }
}
```

The name of the key in the previous db was `name`, but in the newly modified schema, only `username` could be searched, so the variable `name` could not be found.